# Android apk with expansion file on play store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, expansion-files

I had uploaded apk(created using unity) with its expansion file on play store.after publishing the apk,play store download large expansion file (additional file) firstthen small apk file. why ?Actually I want to change the order of downloading for my app, how can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change it.

And I don't see why it matters. The APK needs the expansion file to work, so it downloads the data first and then the executable. What order it's downloaded in doesn't matter.

However, if you for whatever reason want to download it in the apk-> expansion file order, you have to download it from a self-hosted server from the APK. You cannot change the order in which it's downloaded from google play